# How to read elements of child activity by launching it through parent activity using Appium?

Tags: android, appium

I am launching an activity from a previously launched activity. I want to read the elements of the second activity. I am using the following code:

```
List<WebElement> input = (List<WebElement>) dr.findElement(By.id("base_layout")).findElements(By.className("android.widget.ListView"));

int len = input.size();
System.out.println("Input is : "+len);
```

It gives a `NoSuchElementException`. Can someone give some solution for the same?

Comment: I think using Intents will be a better solution

Comment: @MohammadZ It is not supported by Appium.

Comment: @Anurag if possible please share your uiautomator screen

Comment: i would second the thought of sharing the screen hierarchy as suggested by @ShekharSwami to make it clear how you should access the elements.